MSACCESS.EXE process won't end
After applying the quality update for the latest channel (preview version) of Microsoft Access (64-bit), version 2408 (build 17928.20066) dated 8/14, the MSACCESS.EXE process won't end even after closing Microsoft Access application.
The reproduction steps are as follows:

Create a form named Form1.
On Form1, create a command button named Command1.
In the Click event of Command1, write "Application.Quit".

Run the application, click Command1 on Form1 to close the application.
Afterward, when you check the Task Manager, MSACCESS.EXE process won't end.
This issue does not occur in the 32-bit version. I believe this is a bug. Can you advise where I should report this?
Rolling back to version 2407 resolved this issue.

Please add information about your Windows version and build.

Current information here: https://www.accessforever.org/post/error-3048-and-hanging-access-task-in-version-2408

I can confirm this behaviour, though I don't have version 2408:

Version 2407 (Build 17830.20166 Click-to-Run) Current Channel: Closes correctly
Version 2409 (Build 18011.20000 Click-to-Run) Beta Channel: Leaves orphaned process

Windows versions:

2407 runs in Windows 11 Pro 22H2 Build 22621.4037

2409 runs in Windows 10 Pro 22H2 Build 19045.4780


I've reported it to Microsoft.

I solved this problem by making the file location a Trusted location in Access settings. But in my case it was just a "Background process" that was remaining open, not the "App process". So I'm not sure it will help you too, but it's worth a try.
Version 2408 Build 16.0.17928.20114

I have added to Trusted Locations both the folder where my Access front-end resides, and also C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16, but this did not fix it for me.

Did you also try adding the location of the back-end? In my case db file was in subfolder which I included, but if you have your db file somewhere else it might be worh trying

Problem solved only after Microsoft issued a new patch to Office 365 on Tuesday Sept 10th.
